# Stuck in import algs4 with vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I added algs4 into the referenced libraries in java project, but when I compile the following project, vscode keeps showing "RandomWord.java:1: error: package edu.princeton.cs.algs4 does not exist"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the commands to:

`javac -classpath ".;(path to algs4)\algs4.jar" Yourprogram.java`

and

`java -classpath ".;(path to algs4)\algs4.jar" Yourprogram.java`

Then the problem will be solved.

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)